# Realm Object Server (ROS) on AWS: how to make a valid Websocket request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, swift3, realm, realm-mobile-platform

**Setup:**

I am using iOS 11 and Xcode 9

Testing Realm for the first time and considering as an alternative to Firebase. Got a test server up and running in AWS EC based on the Tokyo public AMI provided. Dashboard works, adding users from Swift code works, even realms are created.

**Problem:**

Can not write, getting either 
"Connection[1]: SSL handshake failed: Premature end of input" when I use "realms://" or "Connection[1]: Writing failed: End of input" when using "realm://" as a sync server URL. Tried googling the SSL error and did not find any matches.

From the time the tutorials on Realm website were made lots of the code has changed so I have had to improvise, perhaps there is some really clear mistake or perhaps it's my server config?

Here's my code.

```
var realm: Realm?
    if let serverURL = URL(string: "http://13.112.252.130:9080"){
        let usernameCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: "raul", password: "abc123", register: false)
        SyncUser.logIn(with: usernameCredentials,
                       server: serverURL) { user, error in
                        if let user = user {
                            print("User \(user) is admin: \(user.isAdmin)")
                            if let syncServerURL = URL(string: "realms://13.112.252.130:9080/~/addressBook") {
                                let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: syncServerURL))
                                realm = try? Realm(configuration: config)
                                print("Successfully connected to realm!")
                                let contact = Contact()
                                contact.name = "John Doe"
                                contact.phone = "123456789"
                                contact.email = "john.doe@gmail.com"
                                if let realm = realm {
                                    self.contactResults = realm.objects(Contact.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
                                    try? realm.write {
                                    realm.add(contact)
                                    print("wrote to realm!")
                                }
                                }

                            } else if let error = error {
                                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }
        }
    }
```

Here's the error log with "realsms://" and this goes into a infinite loop:

```
2017-09-02 07:37:18.223475+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703339] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 1
2017-09-02 07:37:18.223532+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703339] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2017-09-02 07:37:18.223551+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703339] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
User is admin: false
Successfully connected to realm!
2017-09-02 07:37:19.319628+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703453] Sync: Opening Realm file: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A52579D-4863-4FC3-88DA-31F2EC2549E5/Documents/realm-object-server/64e042b0-d753-4ebf-b5a4-de8f8f56142f/realms%3A%2F%2F13.112.252.130%3A9080%2F%7E%2FaddressBook
2017-09-02 07:37:19.320459+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703453] Sync: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Starting session for '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A52579D-4863-4FC3-88DA-31F2EC2549E5/Documents/realm-object-server/64e042b0-d753-4ebf-b5a4-de8f8f56142f/realms%3A%2F%2F13.112.252.130%3A9080%2F%7E%2FaddressBook'
2017-09-02 07:37:19.320591+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703453] Sync: Connection[1]: Resolving '13.112.252.130:9080'
2017-09-02 07:37:19.322722+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703453] Sync: Connection[1]: Connecting to endpoint '13.112.252.130:9080' (1/1)
2017-09-02 07:37:19.458271+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703453] Sync: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '13.112.252.130:9080' (from xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
2017-09-02 07:37:19.597335+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703453] Sync: Connection[1]: SSL handshake failed: Premature end of input
2017-09-02 07:37:19.597609+0700 RealmAdressbook[7253:3703453] Sync: Connection[1]: Connection closed due to error
```

And this is the log when I use "realm://", goes into loop as well:

```
2017-09-02 07:41:00.362705+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705293] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 1
2017-09-02 07:41:00.362762+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705293] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2017-09-02 07:41:00.362782+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705293] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
User is admin: false
Successfully connected to realm!
wrote to realm!
2017-09-02 07:41:01.524168+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705496] Sync: Opening Realm file: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/36B5D609-1E8B-48FD-B20A-F5DF4EB21384/Documents/realm-object-server/64e042b0-d753-4ebf-b5a4-de8f8f56142f/realm%3A%2F%2F13.112.252.130%3A9080%2F%7E%2FaddressBook
2017-09-02 07:41:01.525491+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705496] Sync: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Starting session for '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/36B5D609-1E8B-48FD-B20A-F5DF4EB21384/Documents/realm-object-server/64e042b0-d753-4ebf-b5a4-de8f8f56142f/realm%3A%2F%2F13.112.252.130%3A9080%2F%7E%2FaddressBook'
2017-09-02 07:41:01.526011+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705496] Sync: Connection[1]: Resolving '13.112.252.130:9080'
2017-09-02 07:41:01.527816+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705496] Sync: Connection[1]: Connecting to endpoint '13.112.252.130:9080' (1/1)
2017-09-02 07:41:01.663245+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705496] Sync: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '13.112.252.130:9080' (from '192.168.1.4:59862')
2017-09-02 07:41:01.819181+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705496] Sync: Connection[1]: Writing failed: End of input
2017-09-02 07:41:01.819320+0700 RealmAdressbook[7263:3705496] Sync: Connection[1]: Connection closed due to 
error
```

Logs from the server it seems that something is wrong with my request headers, how to fix this?

```
proxy: [syncProxy] internal error: Error: socket hang up at createHangUpError (httpclient.js:253:15) at Socket.socketOnEnd (httpclient.js:345:23) at emitNone (events.js:91:20) at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7) at endReadableNT (streamreadable.js:974:12) at combinedTickCallback (internal/process/nexttick.js:80:11) at process.tickCallback (internal/process/nexttick.js:104:9).
1:51:33 AMinfo
sync: HTTP Connection[714]: Connection closed due to error
1:51:33 AMerror
sync: HTTP Connection[714]: Check the proxy configuration and make sure that the HTTP request is a valid Websocket request. The header values are case sensitive
1:51:33 AMerror
sync: HTTP Connection[714]: The HTTP request with the error is: GET /realm-object-server HTTP/1.1
connection: Upgrade
host: 13.112.252.130
sec-websocket-key: 7FDPgyFxq/GT1tKfIMJNcg==
sec-websocket-protocol: io.realm.sync.19
sec-websocket-version: 13
upgrade: websocket
x-realm-access-token: eyJhY2Nlc3MiOlsiZG93bmxvYWQiLCJ1cGxvYWQiLCJtYW5hZ2UiXSwiYXBwX2lkIjoiY29tLmJhbWJhbWxhYnMuUmVhbG1BZHJlc3Nib29rIiwiZXhwaXJlcyI6MTUwNDM3ODg4NiwiaWQiOiJlMjI0YTM5NmU4YTI0OWU1ODlhNWQ4OWM0ODczOTMzOCIsImlkZW50aXR5IjoiNjE1ZWUxMjU0MDA4ZDA5MWJiYTc1MjU4YTAyZWViZjYiLCJwYXRoIjoiLzYxNWVlMTI1NDAwOGQwOTFiYmE3NTI1OGEwMmVlYmY2L215UmVhbG0ifQ==:hyX8GtVHMIBho3Zw6pZfp9Gnl6O0C0Rl73V0EdX/a4ZWXMxcySFZmWbs0CxmjnpZUDNnFDK3PpXspN1YnGu2c5ByuRIpgpT7hkzwAil2EQzFeKFycYXwTbsp3a6X9npHETjxUfe9QWIIA5drz3VRPUI+0Tj+qspjbyPBcMhL6ZH3A8ubZHOIpjJpxRWGZbghdznf0g71Ta0SDyCYT4GB+fHuddzUH7RZgLkzBfoyIdJyfGccwVi1Qe/c0GTPzkH12TSyzHSwx9PnGadl1vBRuPci6fs+TE03rx6Gy7v73I37JpVVsiPm1omMG7FBdi60iQYQvItiycnle/rvb6+u3w==
x-realm-path: /615ee1254008d091bba75258a02eebf6/myRealm

1:51:33 AMerror
sync: HTTP Connection[714]: There must be a header of the form 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: io.realm.protocol'
1:51:33 AMinfo
sync: HTTP Connection[714]: Received: Sync HTTP request(protocol_version=-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the failure in the SSL case and in the non-SSL case are probably different.

For the SSL case, are you sure that you want to use port 9080?
Usually Realm uses 9443.

For the non-SSL case, the problem is that the headers apparently have been rewritten by an intermediate proxy. The request received by the server is different from expected. We can fix this at Realm. The only thing you can do right now is to change proxy. Thanks for reporting this.

Edited answer: For the non-SSL case, the reason that the headers are not recognized by the server is that you use an older version of the server.
It seems that you have upgraded the client without upgrading the server.
Try using the latest version of the server.